# How to use dictionary a dictionary globally in C#.

Tags: c#, global-variables

I want to use a dictionary data in multiple classes but the dictionary is initialized in a non-static class. I am not interested to use dictionary after making object of that class.

Please help.

Comment: so do you want to use a dictionary or not?

Comment: You can use singleton and put that dictionary inside, override the `Application` class ( if it's WPF ) and store application instance data inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the dictionary as `static`. Class can remain non-static. Now, no matter how many objects of that class are created, they all will refer to same dictionary.